# Why is my variable undefined in TCPDF?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, tcpdf, calculation

My Sql Table

```
+------------+---------+
|    name    |  price  |
+------------+---------+
|     A      |    70   |
+------------+---------+
|     B      |    70   |
+------------+---------+
```

I create a pdf with TCPDF:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");  
    $pdo->execute(); 
    while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
        $result += $row['price'];       
} 

$html = '
<table><tr><th>'.$result.'</th></tr></table>'
;
```

I expect the result to be `140`, but I get an error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: result 
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
```

Note: If I remove the `+` sign. The pdf is created without errors and I get the result `70`.

Comment: make $result = 0; after $pdo->execute(); Now You're trying to add something to not-existent variable :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does what it says on the tin: `$result` is not defined the first time you loop through your data. You can't add anything to it, because it's not defined yet. This should work.

```
$pdo = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");  
    $pdo->execute(); 
    $result = 0.0; // Add this row. I'm assuming 'price' is a decimal
    while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
        $result += $row['price'];       
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that did work!

Answer (score 2):

On the line

```
$result += $row['price'];
```

You make this

```
$result = $result + $row['price'];
```

But the very first time you run the script, the $result variable is not defined.
Add

```
$result = 0;
```

before the $pdo connection or before the while and you should not have any errors anymore.